# Importing OBJ File to the center with correct orientation

Tags: import

I'm trying to work with blender and having a hard time with this program. I would like to import a obj-file as quoted in the title but have finally only managed to see it at least somewhere on my screen. What steps do I need to take to import obj-files properly?

---

This ist what I see after import. I have marked the file in the object list:

[image]

And this is what I see when I go to View > View selected:

[image]

Can this be to small?

Answer (score 3):

If the object is already in the scene, select it. In the 3D viewport, open the transform panel (little cross on the right). You will see the location. Click on X, Y and Z and change their values to 0, this should put the object at the center of the scene.

Here is a picture where you can see which fields you need to change. You can then change the Rotation to give it the desired orientation.
[image]

For the orientation, you can also choose it when you import the OBJ file. When you do File -> Import -> Wavefront, you will be given the choice for the forward and up axes of the object :

[image]

Comment: No matter what I am doing, it doesn't work. My object is somewhere in the nowhere and won't move to the grid.

Comment: @Pingponguin Did you check the dimensions of the object? (same place where you can see the location, rotation, scale... when you click the little cross on the right in 3D view). It's possible that it's inside the cube.

Comment: @Pingponguin Now that your object is scaled, in the 3D view with your object selected, go to Object->Transform and try Origin to Center of mass ( or maybe Origin to Geometry) and then snap or put location at (0,0,0)

Answer (score 1):

First move the cursor to the center with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Center*, or In the 3D view header *Object > Snap > Cursor to Center*. Then import the obj file. All added objects go to the cursor's location. To rotate the imported object select it with <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> then press <kbd>R</kbd>. To constrain the rotation to only a certain axis press either X Y or Z while you are still rotating.

Comment: I have followed your steps but the object is not viewable. But it is listed in the object-list at the right. I guess it is being imported somewhere in the scene but I don't know how to show where and how to get it to the center.

Comment: @Pingponguin press N then scroll up to the top of that panel, what are the X Y and Z values for *Location*? If you press . on the NumPad it will zoom in on the selected object.

Comment: I found it. I selected the object in the  list and went to "View" > "View selected". If I'm reading it right the object is at X: 14.660 Y: 87.475 Z 43.964 but I still don't know how to get it to the center.

Comment: SHIFT C to move the cursor to the grid center (0,0,0,). Then Select the object in object mode. And finally call: Object -> Snap -> Selection to Cursor. Your object's origin should now be placed in the center of the grid (at 0,0,0)

Comment: No matter what I am doing, it doesn't work. My object is somewhere in the nowhere and won't move to the grid.

Comment: @Pingponguin have you tried scaling up your imported model? It may be just too small to see.

Comment: I think the origin of your object is at 0,0,0 even though the geometry isn't. Try pressing Ctrl Alt Shift C *> Geometry to origin* with the imported object selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the object. I set the clamp size to 100 and now I can see it:

[image]

Is there anything I have to consider regarding the size?

Comment: It does not work to snap the object to the curser or grid. I follow the instractions by Gaia Clary